# Is Tradescantia zebrina (inchplant, wandering jew) an edible “crop” plant?

Tags: edible

The inchplant (*Tradescantia zebrina*) is popular due to its undemanding nature and appearance. Considering its purple underpart and silvery texture, I never would’ve dared to *taste* (or eat) it.

[image: Tradescantia zebrina leaves (public domain image from Wikimedia Commons)]

From its [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tradescantia_zebrina) however, I discovered that in Central America, a cold drink is prepared from the leaves, called **(Agua de) Matalí**. I merely found three non-free pictures ([two](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CCffpNTUkAACABb.jpg) [glasses](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-bR12hdhlF9E/TnUGO8v70FI/AAAAAAAAR8M/03Vv_o32nNc/s1600/004+-+Copy.JPG) and a [bottle](http://charricos.com.mx/wps/wp-content/gallery/jugos-carla/matali-limon-maguey.jpg)). Looks good!

This plant usually grows abundantly lush (even in radically different ecosystems). Sometimes you even have to thin out some shoots. It’d be great if you could cultivate it not only for its beauty, but also for its nutritional properties.

**Is there any reliable evidence for its edibility?**

Comment: I've no idea, but would check a broader range of sources for accuracy, and uses other than Wiki. At least it's easy to grow.

Comment: Comprehensive article, in Spanish only: http://www.tlatlauquiysuregion.com.mx/2014/05/el-matlalin.html

Comment: No.  If this were edible it would be listed under edibles, instead it is listed under 'irritating to skin'.  No I would not eat this.  It is beautiful but all 'invasive' competitive plants are usually beautiful...it is one of their gambits for spreading as a species.  Very easy to grow, not so much to grow it properly and have a gorgeous specimen.  Brings me back to my 'hippie' days!  Hey, you can find anything in the internet that you want. I just have to bring this up because it is pertinent.  There are people who actually drink their URINE.  The internet told them it was a miracle drink....

Comment: @stormy: Thanks for this skeptical comment. It’s somewhat contradictory to other information on this question. What do you say to their confirmative nature (and the scarce sources thereunto)? Where have you read about its listing under “irritating to skin”? And to address your example: there’s plenty of uses for urine, including drinking it, which is called [urophagia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urophagia).

Comment: I shall go find this 'sap' of wandering jew that is irritating to the skin.  There are far better edibles all around to eat and survive winter and summer.  Urine, has been touted as 'sterile'...No it is not sterile...has been said to have 99 different chemicals (there are now only 118 elements)?.  I have to grin.  If the body goes to all the work to GET RID of chemicals, water why the hell would anyone think that we humans know better than hundreds of thousands of years of evolution?  Isn't there enough in life to not need to prove oneself by drinking pee?  Just logical thinking...no way...

Comment: "We should mention that the Wandering Jew Plant outdoors tends to become an Invasive species if not properly maintained as it's difficult to eradicate because if only an inch of it survives it will live on. That said, our focus is on the indoor grower and so it's potentially invasive nature outdoors isn't a problem. The Wandering Jew Plant is safe to have around cats and people, the sap however can be irritating so either wear gloves or wash you hands immediately if you come into contact with the sap."

Comment: http://www.ourhouseplants.com/plants/wandering-jew-inch-plant

Answer (score 6):

> Agua de Matali with Mint and Lime
>   Adapted from Chef Christian Bravo, Restaurante Punta del Mar, Merida, Yucatan
>
> Matali is the Mexican name for Tradescantia zebrina (striped) or Tradescantia pallida (purple), a species of spiderwort native to the Gulf Coast of eastern Mexico. In the US, it's known as inch plant, purpleheart, and wandering jew, and it's used for ornamental planting. In Mexico, the leaves are infused to make agua de matali, a refreshing, cool tonic. Chef Christian Bravo riffs on the traditional drink to make a mocktail that he serves in his restaurant Punta del Mar in Merida, Yucatan. Matali grows all over Austin, so we can enjoy it here, too. The purple variety makes an especially pretty presentation.
>
> - 1 cup washed matali leaves
> - 3/4 cup sugar
> - 4 cups water
> - fresh mint leaves
> - 2 tablespoons lime juice
> - Crushed ice
> - Lime wedges for garnish
>
> In a saucepan, bring water and sugar to a boil; add matali leaves and remove from heat. Cover and let rest for five minutes. Strain infused liquid and cool to room temperature.
>
> Place ice in a tall glass, add lime juice and mint leaves, and fill with matali liquid. Stir, then garnish with a slice of lime.

http://www.austinchronicle.com/daily/food/2012-10-11/latin-flavors-american-kitchens-symposium-at-cia-san-antonio/

And since it's Easter, the plant gets its name from the Jew who was cursed to live forever (well, until the second coming) for mocking Jesus of Nazareth who was on his way to Golgotha to be crucified.  Like this unfortunate immortal, the plant is indestructible, and gets everywhere in your garden.

Comment: Thank you for that, And it's flavour is like?

Comment: Indeed, thanks for sharing this recipe and even putting the plant’s common name in seasonal context. However—while I’m really grateful for your answer, appreciate it and am going to try to prepare it—a recipe is in fact a hint, but no reliable evidence.

Answer (score 3):

There is conflicting information on the web regarding the edibility of this plant (for humans), and most of it doesn't seem to be from any major reputable scientific source. It is not listed in any of the Herbal Dictionaries I've checked, including Wiki's list.

Either way, from what information is available, Tradescantia zebrina is not considered one of the culinary herbs, and its use has generally been restricted to medicinal purposes, in the same way as, say, St. John's Wort or Valerian. Considered to 'strengthen the blood' (the jury's out on what that actually means, I've no idea, sounds like nonsense to me), and has been used as a treatment for colds, tuberculosis, high blood pressure and 'problems of the uterus' (again, ?). Some people may have a strong reaction to this plant, either by contact or ingestion, depending on their individual sensitivities. It is, though, perfectly safe for reptiles to consume, though likely only in small amounts:-

http://www.anapsid.org/resources/edible.html.

http://homeguides.sfgate.com/spiderwort-edible-91547.html

http://www.wisegeek.com/what-are-the-medical-uses-of-tradescantia-zebrina.htm

As for the taste of any tisane or tea made from its leaves, I'd imagine most of the pleasure in taste will come from the high amount of sugar and citrus juice rather than the Tradescantia leaves themselves, judging by the recipe given in another answer (reminds me of the recipe for 'nail soup', an old Serbian joke...) So, ultimately, no, I don't think you could consider Tradescantia zebrina a 'crop' plant.

Answer (score 2):

I learned that this plant is edible, when traveling in Uruguay in February 2016. Upon returning home we here at Earthship Biotecture have been eating it in salads all the time, as we have it growing profusely in our greenhouses. It does not have a distinctive taste, but makes the salads look really colorful and beautiful, and I am sure it adds plenty of nutritional value, due to the intense purple color under the leaves.

It is a great plant as it also grows well in low light and shaded spots, which is unusual for a food plant, as most food plants normally need plenty of light to thrive.

This plant definitely gets a space in my greenhouse.

Comment: Thanks for your field report. You obviously made it back without a purple belly, thus a salad with some leaves might pose a good start.